# Checking in IF statement

Tags: php, php-5.6

What is the difference between the following two statements?

Suppose we have the following variable.

```
$someVariable = false;
```

Statements;

```
if($someVariable === false)
```

and

```
if(false === $someVariable)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference you can use it any way you want.You are just checking/comparing 2 values whether they are equal or not.
In simple words it's just like **Is 1+2=3 or 2+1=3??**

Comment: [Commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).

Comment: its about using good coding practice.

Comment: @akshayapandey you will be banned if you exploit the voting for such purposes

Comment: same goes for others as well. Not providing the solutions, but just commenting and commenting

Comment: Are you kidding me..go through my answers..noob